# Joining List to a Pandas Frame - Have I kept the order?

Tags: python, pandas, list, indices

So I have 2 scripts for an Artificial Neural Network on insurance claims - one script is to train/test and one to execute going forward.  I am done with the first one and developing the second one using real production data as a test of it.  The target/class label is a binary 1 or 0.  Input data is initially in a dataframe of shape (5914, 23) and it is all numeric data.  I then do a df.values.tolist() on it, I do StandardScaler() on all values (other than the first one which is a Claim ID) and in the process, it goes through np.asarray.  I then run it through  ANN_Model.Predict_Proba which gives me a list of 5,914 pairs of probabilities.  Now I want to merge back to the dataframe which I had before I did the tolist(),  all of the probabilities (called "predicted_probs") and to do so into a new column on that original dataframe (column called "Results") and to do so for one class (I am only interested in the positive class).  I do so via the following code.  But I don't know if the order of my results is the same as the order of the dataframe.  Is it?

```
for i in range (0,len(predicted_probs)):
    original_df["Results"] = pd.Series(predicted_probs[i])
    print (predicted_probs[[i],[1]])
```

Should I be doing it another way?  I have to replicate what is done in the training script in order to expect like-for-like results, hence the StandardScaler(), np.asarray etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your dataframe's shape is `(5914, 23)` and the output from `ann_model.predict_proba` is `5914`. Since a row from your df will output a single probability you can expect that the order of your results is the same as the order of your dataframe. To add the probability of the positive class to the dataframe,

```
original_df['Results'] = [i[1] for i in predicted_probs]
```

There is no need for you to loop through the `predicted_probs`

Comment: I did try that.  

print("Length is " + str(len(predicted_probs)))  
print ("shape is " + str(original_df.shape))  

  Result is:  
  Length is 5914  
  shape is (5914, 23).  

  Your code results in the error "Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1". I think you're forgetting it is a 2d array (probabilities of both results).  So print ("predicted_probs.shape " + str(predicted_probs.shape)) shows predicted_probs.shape (5914, 2).  Hence my loop to get out one value per claim.  It doesnt feel right and I could end up with the wrong probabilities attached to the wrong claims

Comment: Do you require probabilities for sure or will labels do? You can convert your probabilities to labels using`argmax`

Comment: Yes, definitely need the probability of the positive class rather than just a label

Comment: Then you will have to extract it using a loop. You were right in your thinking.